# after_update callback not acting as expected in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I can't seem to get my callback to function as expected.

```
after_update :erase_reset_token, :on => :update, :if => :password
```

This calls a method on the `User's model` that should erase the password reset token from the database, but should only fire if it is the password that has been touched.

It's gotta be the syntax, but I can't figure it out.  Any help, please?

Comment: try `if: :password_changed?`

Comment: That's not working for me.  I still get a NoMethod error.